# Find the area of cd without a diameter or radius

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A compact disc (CD) is made such that the shortest distance between the edge of the centre hole and the edge of the disc is 53.0 mm. Find the radius of the centre-hole if 1.36% of the disc is removed in making the hole.

Comment: The title and the body of the question don't match: what is it that you want?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose the center hole's radius is $\,r\,$ , then

$$\pi r^2=(0.0136)\pi(53+r)^2\implies 0.9824 r^2-1.4416r-38.2024=0$$

Now just solve the above simple albeit pretty annoying quadratic in $\,r
\,$ ...

Answer (score 1):

Let the radius of the center hole be x. Then from the conditions we have.

$$r = 53 + x, \text{ where r is the radius of the CD}$$

For the area of the center hole we have:

$$P_1 = x^2\pi$$

and for the whole disk we have:

$$P = r^2\pi$$

From the conditions we have

$$P_1 = \frac{1.36}{100} P$$
$$x^2\pi = \frac{136}{10000} r^2\pi$$
$$10000x^2 = 136(53+x)^2$$
$$10000x^2 = 136(2809+106x+x^2)$$
$$10000x^2 = 382024 + 14416x + 136x^2$$
$$9864x^2 - 14416x - 382024 = 0$$

Solving this quadratic equation we get two solutions:

$$x = \frac{53 (17+25 \sqrt{34})}{1233}$$
$$x = \frac{53 (17-25 \sqrt{34})}{1233}$$

Because the radius must be positive number we have:

$$ x = \frac{53 (17+25 \sqrt{34})}{1233} \approx 7$$

So the radius of the center hole is 7 mm

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that the radius of the disk is $r$.

So therefore $r=53+x$ where $x$ is radius of hole.

The area, $A$ of the disk is
$$A_{disk}=\pi r^2$$
$$A_{disk}=\pi (53+x)^2$$

We also know that

$$A_{hole}=\pi x^2$$
$$A_{hole}=0.0136A_{disk}$$

This is because we know that the area of the hole is what they took out of the CD

So since $A_{hole}=\pi x^2$, and $A_{hole}=0.0136A_{disk}$, so we can make the statement

$$\pi x^2=0.0136A_{disk}$$

And since we know the area of the disk,

$$\pi x^2=0.0136[\pi (53+x)^2]$$
$$x^2=0.0136(53+x)^2$$
$$10000x^2=136(x+53)^2$$
$$10000x^2=136(x^2+106x+2809)$$
$$10000x^2=136x^2+14416x+382024$$
$$9864x^2-14416x-382024=0$$
$$2466x^2-3604x-95506=0$$
$$1233x^2-1802x-47753=0$$
$$x=\frac{1802\pm \sqrt{3247204+235517796}}{2466}$$
$$x=\frac{1802\pm \sqrt{238765000}}{2466}$$

Accounting for the positive only,

$$x=\frac{1802+\sqrt{238765000}}{2466}$$

X is about 6.9967 which is about 7 units so therefore the radius of the hole is 7 units.